# Where can I find all form display options types for custom entity fields?

Tags: 8, entities

I created a custom entity with `drupal generate:entity:content`.

I am adding fields in the `baseFieldDefinitions` method of the entity class.

Below is what drupal console generates by default for the `name` field.

Where I can find a list of all possible `type` values for `->setDisplayOptions('form')`. For example, the field below uses `string_textfield`.

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    ...
    $fields['name'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Name'))
      ->setDescription(t('The name of the entity.'))
      ->setSettings([
        'max_length' => 50,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ])
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are field widget plugin IDs.

You can get all of those by querying the field widget plugin manager (service ID: `plugin.manager.field.widget`).

E.g. to get all the IDs in your entity class (once the service is injected):

```
$widget_types = $this->fieldWidgetPluginManager->getDefinitions();
$plugin_ids = array_keys($widget_types);
```

Same thing in procedural code in case someone wants it:

```
$widget_types = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.field.widget')->getDefinitions();
$plugin_ids = array_keys($widget_types);
```

If your current context allows you to inject the widget plugin manager service rather than get it from `\Drupal`, all the better.

Comment: Good answer, this should be in d.org docs, noobs will be searching for info of what they can add and there is no info on that. So people will be lost.

Comment: The answer is for setDisplayOptions('form'), but for setDisplayOptions('view'), do you know the possible plugin options for the type parameter?

Comment: `plugin.manager.field.formatter` for view (field formatter) options.